# Json Array from JsonObject

Tags: android

I reading this Json , I have created the classes as below , My challange is how to read   MultipleChoices to its model class from the response

```
  [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Question": "Suggest areas of improvement in the running of coretec with regards to information technology",
        "HasMultipleChoices": "0",
        "MultipleChoices": []
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Question": "Did you enjoy last year's team building and what suggestions would you have for tbhis year's teambuilding?",
        "HasMultipleChoices": "0",
        "MultipleChoices": []
      },
      {
        "Id": "3",
        "Question": "Do you think the support you get from management in carrying out your tasks is sufficient?",
        "HasMultipleChoices": "1",
        "MultipleChoices": [
          {
            "Id": "1",
            "MultipleChoice": "Yes"
          },
          {
            "Id": "2",
            "MultipleChoice": "No"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

This is my mulitple class

```
public class MultipleChoice {

public String id;
public String multipleChoice;

public MultipleChoice(String id, String multipleChoice) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.multipleChoice = multipleChoice;
}
```

}

This is my Question Class model

```
public class Questions {
    public int id;
    public String Questions;
    public String HasMultipleChoices;
    public String MultipleChoices;
    public List<MultipleChoice> multipleChoices = null;

    public Questions(int id, String Questions ,String HasMultipleChoices, List<MultipleChoice> multipleChoices) {
       this.Questions = Questions;
        this.id = id;
        this.HasMultipleChoices = HasMultipleChoices;
        this.multipleChoices = multipleChoices;
    }

}
```

and this this is how am reading the json through volley

```
        public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Do something with the response
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    JSONArray jsonarray;
                    List<Questions> list = new ArrayList<>();

                    try {
                        jsonarray  = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            //  String ProductName,Price,Category,Description,Brand,Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4,Image5;
                            JSONObject jobObject =jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Questions item= new Questions(jobObject.getInt("Id"),jobObject.getString("Question")
                                    ,jobObject.getString("HasMultipleChoices"),"WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO HAVE A LIST OF MULITPLECHOICES?");

                            list.add(item);
                        }
                        updateList(list);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
        public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Do something with the response
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                JSONArray jsonarray;
                List<Questions> list = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    jsonarray  = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        //  String ProductName,Price,Category,Description,Brand,Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4,Image5;
                        JSONObject jobObject =jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONArray multipleChoice=jobObject.getJSONArray("MultipleChoices");
       List<MultipleChoice> multipleChoiceList=new ArrayList<>();
       if(multipleChoice.length()>0)
     {          
     for (int j=0; j<multipleChoice.length(); j++)
                    {
     JSONObject jsonObject =multipleChoice.getJSONObject(j);
       MultipleChoice mc=new    MultipleChoice(jsonObject.getInt("Id"),jsonObject.getString("MultipleChoice"));
       multipleChoiceList.add(mc);
      }
     }
                        Questions item= new Questions(jobObject.getInt("Id"),jobObject.getString("Question")
                                ,jobObject.getString("HasMultipleChoices"),multipleChoiceList);

                        list.add(item);
                    }
                    updateList(list);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Changed the line   JSONObject jsonObject =jsonarray.getJSONObject(j); to JSONObject jsonObject =  multipleChoice.getJSONObject(j); and it worked . Thanks

Comment: Thanks @WanjalaAlex, by mistake I wrote that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSONArray arr = jobObject.getJSONArray("MultipleChoices");` . Send as parameter and in constructor loop through and convert to needed List.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

It automatically handle everything.

You just need to define Object model.

For your problem, you do not need to do anything if you use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 0):

`jobObject.getJSONArray("MultipleChoice")` will return a `JSONArray` object to you. You have to iterate this to create a `List<MultipleChoice>`. Something like the sample below.

```
JSONArray multiChoiceArray = jobObject.getJSONArray("MultipleChoice");
List<MultipleChoice> multipleChoices = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < multiChoiceArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject multipleChoiceJSON = (JSONObject) multiChoiceArray.get(i);
  multipleChoices.add(new MultipleChoice(multipleChoiceJSON.getInt("Id"),
          multipleChoiceJSON.getInt("multipleChoice")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
//                Questions item= new Questions(jobObject.getInt("Id"),jobObject.getString("Question")
//                        ,jobObject.getString("HasMultipleChoices"),"WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO HAVE A LIST OF MULITPLECHOICES?");
                JSONArray multipleChoices = jobObject.getJSONArray("MultipleChoices");
                if (multipleChoices != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < multipleChoices.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject multipleChoicesJsonObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = multipleChoicesJsonObject.getInt("id");
                        String MultipleChoice = multipleChoicesJsonObject.getString("MultipleChoice");

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray multiplechoice= jobObject.getJSONArray("MultipleChoices");
List<MultipleChoice> listmultiple=new ArrayList<>()
for(int i=0;i<multiplechoice.length();i++)

 {  JsonObject multiplechoiceobj=multiplechoice.getJSONObject(i);
    MultipleChoice mul=new MultipleChoice(multiplechoiceobj.getString("id"),multiplechoiceobj.getString("MultipleChoice"));
    listmultiple.add(mul);
 }
```

Then add this list to

```
Questions item= new Questions(jobObject.getInt("Id"),jobObject.getString("Question")
                                ,listmultiple);
```